# JQuery Print Function Won't Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="button" value="PRINT TIMESHEET" style="height:115px; width:350px; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold;" onclick="print();">

function print() {
    if ($('#rate').val() > 1) { 
        window.print();
    }
    else { 
        alert('You need to fill in a value for hourly rate'); 
    }
}
```

the alert works and if I put something else other than window.print(); it will execute (so I know it is window.print() that is the problem), but for some reason I can't get window.print to work without doing something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
```

I am using Chrome currently and trying to make sure it works there before I start preparing my page to work with other browsers.

Thanks,
-CD

Comment: If the "alert works", then you're obviously getting into the `else` block and not the `if` block... which actually does the `window.print()`.  Try placing distinct alerts in each block, and see which one is firing under the conditions you describe.  Also, where's your html?  Can't you just use a `<button onclick="print();">Print This</button>` rather than an `<input>`?  You're really not giving us much to work with.

Comment: That would never happen...if the `if` condition is satisfied it will execute the  statements inside if block only and the `else` block would never be executed. May be some error in your logic..please debug it once more and if the issue still persists, please share a fiddle with us..

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmxj8ue/2/). Does the print window open immediately? If not, then maybe you have the print preview dialog disabled in Chrome.

Comment: Notice, that comparing strings with `<` or `>` might give you unexpected results. Convert the input value to a number before comparing. Just one more thing, functions and variables in the global scope are actually properties of `window`, you've overridden the native `print` method with your own function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overridden the native `window.print` method by declaring a [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Global_variables) `print` function. Rename your function, and your code will work.

Also, values from inputs are always strings, it's better to convert a string to number before comparing it to another number. For example like this:

```
if (+($('#rate').val()) > 1) { ... }
```

Comment: Isolating the problem, it seemed to be the first case where I needed to rename my function. Thank you!